# Installing PhotoShop CS5 in windows XP error: (when up to 12% of the installation);

Tags: windows-xp, adobe-photoshop

Error Log:

```
----------

Exit Code: 6


-------------------------------------- Summary --------------------------------------


 - 0 fatal error(s), 43 error(s), 41 warning(s)


WARNING: The payload: Adobe Photoshop CS5 Core  {7DFEBBA4-81E1-425B-BBAA-06E9E5BBD97E} requires a UI parent with following specification:

    Family: Photoshop

    ProductName: Adobe Photoshop CS5 Core_x64

    This parent relationship is not satisfied, because this payload is not present in this session.


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure


ERROR: The following payload errors were found during install:


ERROR:  - Adobe CSXS Infrastructure CS5: Install failed


ERROR:  - Microsoft_VC90_ATL_x86: Install failed


ERROR:  - Adobe Media Player: Install failed


ERROR:  - Microsoft_VC90_CRT_x86: Install failed


ERROR:  - Adobe Photoshop CS5 Support: Install failed


ERROR:  - Adobe Bridge CS5: Install failed


ERROR:  - Microsoft_VC80_ATL_x86: Install failed


ERROR:  - DeviceCentral_DeviceCentral3LP-zh_CN: Install failed


ERROR:  - Adobe XMP Panels CS5: Install failed


ERROR:  - Photoshop Camera Raw: Install failed


ERROR:  - AdobeColorCommonSetCMYK: Install failed


ERROR:  - Adobe Mini Bridge CS5: Install failed


ERROR:  - Adobe Photoshop CS5 Chinese Language Pack_AdobePhotoshop12-zh_CN: Install failed


ERROR:  - Adobe ReviewPanel CS5: Install failed


ERROR:  - Microsoft_VC90_MFC_x86: Install failed


ERROR:  - Suite Shared Configuration CS5: Install failed


ERROR:  - Adobe Linguistics CS5: Install failed


ERROR:  - DeviceCentral: Failed due to Language Pack installation failure


ERROR:  - AdobeColorEU CS5: Install failed


ERROR:  - AdobeTypeSupport CS5: Install failed


ERROR:  - AdobeColorVideoProfilesCS CS5: Install failed


ERROR:  - AdobeColorCommonSetRGB: Install failed


ERROR:  - Adobe Photoshop CS5 Core: Failed due to Language Pack installation failure


ERROR:  - Adobe CSXS Extensions CS5: Install failed


ERROR:  - AdobeOutputModule: Install failed


ERROR:  - Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86: Install failed


ERROR:  - Adobe WinSoft Linguistics Plugin CS5: Install failed


ERROR:  - AdobePDFL CS5: Install failed


ERROR:  - AdobeCMaps CS5: Install failed


ERROR:  - AdobeColorNA CS5: Install failed


ERROR:  - Required Common Fonts Installation: Install failed


ERROR:  - Adobe SwitchBoard 2.0: Install failed


ERROR:  - Microsoft_VC80_MFC_x86: Install failed


ERROR:  - AdobeColorPhotoshop CS5: Install failed


ERROR:  - Microsoft_VC80_MFCLOC_x86: Install failed


ERROR:  - PDF Settings CS5: Install failed


ERROR:  - Recommended Common Fonts Installation: Install failed


ERROR:  - Adobe Extension Manager CS5: Install failed


ERROR:  - AdobeColorJA CS5: Install failed


ERROR:  - AdobeJRE: Install failed


ERROR:  - Adobe ExtendScript Toolkit CS5: Install failed


ERROR:  - Adobe AIR: Install failed


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I hava tried many time and the issue is still there, any help will be appriciated, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but do you have 64-bit Windows installed?

Comment: Yeah, the error log seems to point into this direction: it wants to install to Win XP 64, but it says that it cannot find it. Check whether you have XP 32 or 64 bit. And check what system requirements are on the box (I thought that the intall disk contained both versions, but who knows...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem attempting to install CS5 Update to Win 7 64bit using an original Adobe install DVD.  I tried many of the suggestions available in this forum and on the Web.  I did not check the error log until much later.  Should have done so immediately.

A target reference for My Pictures was pointed to a mapped network drive that had changed names a while ago.  For whatever reason, CS5 would not install until it had a valid folder name for My Pictures.  I had to change the references in the registry (as well as removing the reference to the defunct mapped network driver wherever I could find it).  Voila!  Installed without a hitch and now runs fine.